# Is the limit of $\frac{3^x}{2^x}$ when $x$ approaches $+\infty$ indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, limits

is the limit of $\dfrac{3^x}{2^x}$ when $x$ approaches $+\infty$ indeterminate or does it exist?
Thank you

Comment: its indeterminate

Comment: We have $3^x$ growing faster than $2^x$ as x grows larger, therefore, the function approaches infinity

Comment: This seems to be a question of fashion. Twenty years ago, no one would have said it was indeterminate, they would have said the limit was $+\infty$. Today many, perhaps most, people seem to prefer to say it is indeterminate. In any case it is obvious that $1.5^x$ increases monotonically and is unbounded.

Comment: We don't say limits are indeterminate. It's the specific form in which we write the thing we're taking the limit after partially evaluating it at the limit point that we may call indeterminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is in the *indeterminate form* $\infty/\infty$, which only means there is no general theorem for deducing the value of the limit.

When you rewrite it as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x(\log3-\log2)}
$$
you realize that, since $\log3-\log2>0$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3^x}{2^x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x(\log3-\log2)}=
\infty
$$
Whether you accept $\infty$ as a limit or not depends on “local conventions”, but I would never talk about an “indeterminate limit”.

Similarly,
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3^x}{2^x}=
\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{x(\log3-\log2)}=
0
$$
though the limit presents itself in the indeterminate form $0/0$.

Answer (score 4):

It is $+\infty$ as

$3^{x}/2^{x}=(3/2)^{x}$, and $3/2>1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}a^x=\infty$ for $a>1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is an indeterminate form for which the limit doesn't exist.

Indeed,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3^x}{2^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac32\right)^x$$ which is unbounded.

Comment: However, $(3/2)^{\infty}$ is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: @Hurkyl: of course, otherwise my argument would be silly.